# SQL Select within a range of seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the table below

```
2012-05-24 19:00:00.000
2012-07-27 15:51:18.750
2012-07-30 09:40:25.333
2012-07-30 14:25:27.563
2012-07-27 15:51:18.750
2012-07-30 09:40:25.333
2012-07-30 14:25:27.563
2012-05-12 09:23:16.850
2012-05-12 18:00:00.000
```

I am trying to do a range select, so for example

```
SELECT * FROM RUN WHERE RUN_DATETIME = '14:25:29.563'
```

This is a very simple select, but my problem is that the date I am searching code be up too 30 seconds out from what is in the table above, so I need to be able to do the same as above but with a 30 second window and I am not sure what the best way to do this is.

This select is not based on another row, just the rows RUN_DATE within the window.

I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM RUN
WHERE RUN_DATETIME < DATEDADD(s, '14:25:29.563', 30) AND
      RUN_DATETIME > DATEDADD(s, '14:25:29.563', -30)
```

More complicated looking than podiluska's answer, but this works with indexes by pre-calculating the range.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM RUN 
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(s, RUN_DATETIME , '14:25:29.563' ))< 30
```

Comment: If you do that you can't use an index, so this may be slow since it has to run the calculation on each row.

Comment: I agree with @Ariel - Do *not* embed search fields in functions or calculations.

Comment: +1 good answer.  Write queries that are simple and clear.  Look at performance only when a performance problem pops up.

Comment: @Andomar it does not hurt to be proactive, especially with SQL queries.

Comment: @Andomar That's usually good advice, but poorly written database queries can become pathologically slow.

Comment: @Magnus: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." [- Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @Andomar - Also, I would contend that if a search field does not need to be embded in a calculation, it's *usually* best not to do so. This is because the increase in complexity is usually trivial *(often complexity actually decreases, it's just length of code that increases)*, it allows standardised patterns and practices, and future optimisations then only require indexing rather than also re-writing queries. Also, it allows them to incidentally benefit from indexes added for other reasons.

Comment: @Andomar You are over-applying this. Like all rules, if you follow it slavishly you will get in trouble. A good way to tell is how much extra time it takes to make the optimization - in this case virtually no time at all. Knuth was warning against spending lots of time on complicated optimizations that you don't even know are necessary. He would approve of simple to implement optimizations like this.

Comment: Very good comment there @Dems, that is exactly the reason to why you should do it without the function. Also the readability of the query is actually better without using `ABS`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  RUN
WHERE
      RUN_DATETIME >= DATEADD(second, -30, '14:25:29.563')
  AND RUN_DATETIME <  DATEADD(second,  30, '14:25:29.563')
```

This is longer than the `ABS(DATEDIFF())` version.  It is, however, much faster when applied to indexed fields.

That is because the optimiser can easily see that you want all records within one sequential block.  It can search for the start, then search for the end, and return everything between.

The `ABS(DATEDIFF())` variation requires every row to be checked independantly, and makes no use of indexes or range seeks.  It's a full scan of the whole table.

**EDIT:**

Also note that I use `>=` and `<`.  This is standard practice for ranges of time.

For example `val >= 0 AND val < 60` and `val >= 60 AND val < 120` ensures that the value at `val = 60` is only counted in one range of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think RUN_DateTime column contains Date and comparison we are doing is with only Time here '14:25:29.563'. I agree with podiluska's answer. Just we would need to convert '14:25:29.563' to a date by taking out Day, month, year from RUN_DateTime column. We can do it by Date_Part function.